# Re($f(z)$)$=$Im($f(z))$ implies $f$ is constant over connected domain of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose

$$f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$$

is holomorphic with $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ connected domain.

Show if Re$f(z)$$=$Im$f(z)$ for all $z \in D$ then $f$ is constant.

My thoughts so far. We can let $f(z) = a+ai$ if $z \in D$.

Then $f(z) = a(1+i)$ for this particular $z \in D$.
and in general say $f(z)=a_i(i+1)$

Comment: Do you mean $\text{Re}(f(z))=\text{Im}(f(z))$ for all $z\in D$?

Comment: oh omy gosh YES, then I need to re try this from scratch !

Comment: note that $f(z)\cdot f(z)$ i.e. is also holomorphic and purely imaginary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(z)=u(z)+iu(z)$ be defined on a connected domain $D \subset \mathbb{C}$

By the C-R equations, we have that

$$u_x=u_y$$
$$u_y=-u_x$$

which forces $u$ to be constant and thus $f'(z)=0$ on the defined connected domain of $\mathbb{C}$

Lemma, if $f'(z)=0$ on open connected domain of $\mathbb{C}$, then its constant.

Since we have a connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$ its path connected, so let $z_0\in D$ and let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ then define the path between them to be $\gamma$, then

\begin{align}
f(z)-f(z_0)&= \int_\gamma f'(z)dz\\
&=\int_\gamma 0 dz\\
&= 0
\end{align}

Thus $f(z)=f(z_0)$ and $f$ is constant on $D$.

Comment: That was not cool.

Comment: @copper.hat sorry but your method isn't as clear to me. This method, using the C-R equations seems more natural to me.

Answer (score 3):

The open mapping theorem is the appropriate result here.

Another approach would be to define $\phi(z) = \operatorname{re} z - \operatorname{im}z$ and note that $\phi(f(z)) = 0$ for $z \in D$.

If $f'(z_0) \neq 0$ and $t$ is real, note that $ { f(z_0+t {1 \over f'(z_0}) ) -f(z_0) \over t} \to 1$ which is a contradiction since $\phi({ f(z_0+t {1 \over f'(z_0}) ) -f(z_0) \over t}  ) = 0$ but $\phi(1) = 1$. Hence $f'(z) = 0$ for all $z \in D$.

Pick some $z_0 \in D$ and let $S = \{ z \in D | f(z) =f(z_0) \}$. Since $f$ is continuous, $S$ is clearly closed. The power series expansion of $f$ at any $z$ shows that $S$ is open, hence $S = D$.

Comment: how do you go from $f$ continuous thus $S$ is clearly closed? The PREIMAGES of closed sets are closed under continuous maps not images. Oh never mind, you just said $S$ is clearly closed. I don't see that with continuity of $f$ sorry.

Comment: The inverse image of a closed set $\{ f(z_0) \}$ by a continuous function is closed.

Comment: I mean closed relative to $D$.

Comment: Ah so you expressed it as the inverse image of a closed set in the range?

Comment: Yes, since $D$ is connected, the only sets contained in $D$ that are both relatively open and closed are $D$ and the empty set.

Comment: Could I just appeal to the C-R equations?

Comment: Of course. I am not suggesting that this is the only way. However even if you use the Cauchy Riemann equations, you will still need to make an argument based on connectedness.

Comment: so I get that $u_x=u_y$ and $u_y=-u_x$ on $D$ which is connected. Where does the argument for connected ness fall into play? so I know the $f(D)$ needs to be connected as well by continuity of $f$.

Comment: The Cauchy Riemann equations show that $f'(z) = 0$ on $D$. You have to then conclude that this means that $f$ is constant on $D$. If $D$ was not connected, say for example $D= B(0,1) \cup B(3,1)$ then $f$ could be $0$ on the first ball and one on the second and so $f$ would not be constant even though $f'(z) = 0$. So, connectedness is essential to determining that $f$ is constant.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Did something change?

Answer (score 2):

The Open Mapping theorem gives this to you immediately. What is your level of knowledge?

Comment: I have to prove without open mapping theorem,

Comment: I think I need to use connected ness.

Comment: What do the Cauchy Riemann Equations telll you?

Comment: tells me that $u_x=u_y$ and $u_y=-u_x$. Since the real part and imaginary parts are equal.

Comment: check my proof tell me if it works